"ERC20: transfer amount exceeds balance"
I try to send VivaFTN from wallet 1 to wallet 2, but it shows the following error:
Preparing to transfer VIVAFTN to 0xea078983f6Ae89bB5e2fAE5e531cE11B1B845292
Error: execution reverted: "ERC20: transfer amount exceeds balance" (action="estimateGas", data="0x08c379a00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002645524332303a207472616e7366657220616d6f756e7420657863656564732062616c616e63650000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000", reason="ERC20: transfer amount exceeds balance", transaction={ "data": "0xa9059cbb000000000000000000000000ea078983f6ae89bb5e2fae5e531ce11b1b8452920000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000adb18ad80e7d980000", "from": "0x50352A5B2Ab9254Ab49870F1D671616F8791171b", "to": "0xf93D24c03344B5e697ad83D59cAa1c5817973365" }, invocation=null, revert={ "args": [ "ERC20: transfer amount exceeds balance" ], "name": "Error", "signature": "Error(string)" }, code=CALL_EXCEPTION, version=6.13.0)

My wallet has enough VivaFTN balance for the gas fee and the transaction.
This is my transferVivaFtn function:
async function transferVivaFtn(privateKey, receiverAddress, amount) {
    const wallet = new Wallet(privateKey, (await provider));

    const contractWithSigner = contract.connect(wallet);

    const gasPrice = await getGasPrice();

    const tx = await contractWithSigner.transfer(receiverAddress, amount, {
        gasPrice: gasPrice
    });
    return tx.hash;
}

And this is the getGasPrice function:
async function getGasPrice() {
    let feeData = (await provider.getFeeData())
    const gasPrice = feeData.gasPrice.toString()
    return gasPrice
}

